# NodeJS app can run locally but not on EC2 - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I was deploying my node js app to ec2. And when I run `npm start`, it returns an error like this:

```
npm start

> skillsme-server@1.0.0 start
> node -r esm index.js

/home/ec2-user/reponame/index.js:1
SyntaxError: The requested module 'file:///home/ec2-user/reponame/general/general.js' does not provide an export named 'randomFunction'
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

But that function does exist and the repo can run perfectly fine locally. `npm i` is tried, not working.

What could be the problem?

UPDATE:
The strangest thing is I have another branch of the same repo running in the same instance, and that branch is running perfectly fine. The functions triggering error also exist there. When I switch the repo in this folder to that branch, the problem still occurs here.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, there is a js file called `general.js` from where the code is trying to import a `randomFunction`, however it seems that it has not been exported. So try exporting `randomFunction` from `general.js`

Comment: @ArpanKc The problem is that ```randomFunction``` has been exported in the file.

Comment: are there any other functions inside of general.js that are working just fine?

Comment: @MohamedAljamil There are some work fine and some do not. I removed 2 functions from it and all other files calling those 2 functions, then the error disappeared.